# Is there any Design Pattern for calling object methods statically

Tags: php, algorithm, design-patterns, static

Basically I am trying to make a library for handling files and directories.

The idea is there will be separate classes for `FileFinding`, `FileReading`, `FileWriting` etc.

What I am trying to search is there any design pattern to achieve something like :

There is just once class lets say

```
<?php namespace vendor/FileHandler;

 class FileHandler {}
```

Now in the library I have specific classes let say

```
<?php namespace vendor/FileHandler;

class FileFinder 
{
     /**
     * Find files by their types
     * 
     * @param string $path path to find files in.
     * @param mixed $type string or array of file type/types (extensions).
     * @return array array of file names.
     */
    public function findFilesByType($path, $type)
    {
        // do logic here.
        return $files;
    }
}
```

Now I want my library users to call the `FileFinder::findFilesByType()` by using the main class `FileHandler::findFilesByType();`

Please note: The `FileFinder::findFilesByType()` is not static method but I want it to be utilized as static method from `class FileHanlder`

**Updated:**
The question I have asked above seems similar to Laravel's Facade pattern. But their implementation going above my head. Even I'm not sure if Facade pattern will do this.

Comment: visit-http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Another one->http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382206/php-uses-static-methods-in-object-context

Comment: @SagarNaliyapara your links does not answer my problem.

Comment: FileFinder should be dependent on FileHandler, but it's not possible with static calling. So another way is extend abstract FileHandler with FileFinder. Then you can call FileHandler's methods and users can't use abstract class directly... But I'm not sure that's a good practise..

Comment: Removed the OOP tag because what you want to do is the opposite of OOP.

Comment: @PeeHaa What i want to do is wrong approach ?

Comment: If the aim is writing OOP code yes your approach is wrong.

Comment: @PeeHaa Can you please point out the thing  i m doing against OOP so that i can look for some other approach. ? Thanks for highlighting the most important point.

Comment: Because you are basically just using functions instead of objects if you do `Foo::bar()`.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the violation of OOP (resp. the violation of law of demeter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The facade should keep a static instance of every class that provides functionality you yourself want to forward to the library users.

In the facade's static methods, utilize the above objects and forward the method calls to them.
Only use this approach, if the objects you forward to are stateless,
otherwise you have to create the appropriate objects inside the facades method, in order to not propagate state information between method calls.

In the following a little example in java, but you'll get the point

```
public class Facade {
    private static final HashComputer computer = new HashComputer();

    // since this operation changes state of accumulator,
    // it has to create one on each invocation
    public static List<String> accumulate(String... args) {
        Accumulator acc = new Accumulator();
        for (String arg : args)
            acc.add(arg);

        return acc.collect();
    }

    // this operation does not change state of the object it delegates to,
    // so there is no need to create a new instance on every invocation
    public static int computeHash(String s) {
        return computer.hashFor(s);
    }

    // has stateless instances
    private static class HashComputer {
        public int hashFor(String s) {
            return s.hashCode();
        }
    }

    // instances have state depending on state of list
    private static class Accumulator {
        List<String> arguments = new ArrayList<String>();
        public void add(String s) {
            arguments.add(s);
        }
        public List<String> collect() {
            return Collections.unmodifiableList(arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

Strictly speaking this exact way of implementing a facade just suits your needs. A facade does not have to be a utility class with static methods, it can also be an instance of a class.

The principles behind the facade design pattern are abstracting from the intrinsics of a group of classes (or of a whole layer) that are responsible for some common functionality, encapsulating the operations and granting easy, maybe high-level, access to them.

---

As @PeeHaa mentioned in his comment, this static facade approach indeed is not in the sense of OOP, because violates the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), which says:

A method `method` of a class `Class` should only call methods

- of `Class`
- of an object created by `method`
- on the arguments of `method`
- on instance variables of `Class`

You don't use a facade with static methods in that sense, since you call the methods on the class and not on instances of it.

Comment: Thanks i got the concept. Can you please provide your comment as How this approach is against OOP as @PeeHaa mentioned in his comment. I just want to be clear before going further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `__callStatic`

```
<?php

namespace vendor/FileHandler;

class FileHandler {

/**  PHP >= 5.3.0  */
public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {

  if($name == 'findFilesByType') {
    $obj = new FileFinder();
    return $obj->findFilesByType(implode(', ', $arguments));      
  }   
}
}
?>
```

Call:

```
FileHandler::FileHandler('/files', 'pdf');
```

Reas more at:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic

Comment: This seems like a working solution but i have 100 methods divided into 5 classes . It would be too long to do so many `if`. What do you think ?

Comment: @RaheelKhan you can combine my answer with Reflection http://php.net/ReflectionClass I'm tired, in my country are 6:20 am and I spent the whole night awake