# How to add a fuction in a model yii2

Tags: yii2

I have modified my signup form, I add a field that called billCode, so I want add a function to my signForm model to random integer number, I have a function to random integr and I put that into signup form model like this

```
class SignupForm extends Model {
    // ...
    // ...

    public static function randomNumber()
    {
        $randBill = '';
        for ($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
            $randBill .= mt_rand(0, 9);
        }
        return  $randBill;
    }

    public function signup()
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return null;
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();

        $user->billCode = randomNumber();

        return $user->save() ? $user : null;
    }
}
```

when I press the submit button in signUp Form, yii2 keep give me this error

> Call to undefined function frontend\models\randomNumber()

Any help?

Comment: `randomNumber` is a static function, you can't call it just by `randomNumber()`. Using `self::randomNumber()` could be work.

Comment: @paul, thank you very much, it work

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Comment: @paul add it as answer or else let me answer :)

Comment: @InsaneSkull :)

Answer (score 1):

*Copy from comment*

`randomNumber` is a static function, you can't call it just by `randomNumber()`. Using `self::randomNumber()` could be work.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it by `self` keyword

```
class SignupForm extends Model {
    // ...
    // ...

    public static function randomNumber()
    {
        $randBill = '';
        for ($i=0; $i < 8; $i++){
            $randBill .= mt_rand(0, 9);
        }
        return  $randBill;
    }

    public function signup()
    {
        if (!$this->validate()) {
            return null;
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->setPassword($this->password);
        $user->generateAuthKey();

        //$user->billCode = $this->randomNumber();
       $user->billCode = self::randomNumber();

        return $user->save() ? $user : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Do not call static method using object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14382206/php-uses-static-methods-in-object-context) although it's about a good practice :)